# Changing proxy generated URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I wish to update the proxy generated default Url. I have followed [How to change WSO2 ESB URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238512/how-to-change-wso2-esb-url) but the solution provided there was not working and even i wish to block generating two urls for soap bindings depending on version.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect to the default URL from the main sequence of the ESB. Following article explains the configurations

http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/08/access-wsdl-for-customuri-wso2-esb.html